# How to design schema in order to optimize UI filters populations and filtering?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say in RDBS we have two tables:

[image]

In the context of a user interface displaying `Users` details, if we want to have filters by `company name` and `size` we can perform fast SQL queries to get values in the format below:

```
CompanyID       CompanyName
101             Microsoft
102             Google
...

CompanyIDsCSV   Size 
101, 102        100000+
..
```

As data is normalized the operations are expected to be fast.

In the context of MongoDB I can use the embedded collection:

```
{
   UserID: ...
  ,FirstName: ...
  ,LastName: ...
  ,Company:
   {
      ID: ...
     ,Name: ...
     ,Size: ...
   }
}
```

But in order to load the data in the filters initially, I need to read all documents. Can one share how this can be optimize in the context of MongoDB?

What I am thinking is:

- have the data embedded in order to read at once all details I need
- create separate collection with unique companies and used to populate filters values
- create index on `company.id` in order to search by it when filters are used

In the MongoDB documentation there are guidelines for [Embedded and Normalized data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models), but I am wondering would be a bad practice to model my data like this?

I know, I need to ensure the data between the embedded and normalized collections is the same, but I am ready to pay the cost in order to get maximum performance on read.

Comment: If you go with embedded style, it would be great to put an index on `UserID` and `company.id`. You will need always `UserID` to do a index scan and then an index scan on the embedded array otherwise you will have a collection scan on users and an index scan on companies. If you cant provide the UserID always, its better to go seperate with 2 collections

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point.